# Private Messaging Message model design ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, signalr

I am developing a private messaging system using SignalR, ASP.NET MVC,Entity Framework code first. 
The problem is designing the Message table. I want to pull all user with their conversation with me. Say i have two model..

```
  public class User{
        public string UserId{ get;set;}
        public string UserName{get;set;}
  }

  public class Message{
        public string MessageId { get; set;}
        public string MessageContent { get; set;}
        public string SenderId { get; set;} // message sender
        public string ReceiverId { get; set;} //message receiver
        public virtual User Sender { get; set;} // for navigation
        public virtual User Receiver { get; set;}
  }
```

Now i need to get all users associate to their conversation with me.Is there any way to associate those two model using navigation property? or Should i check in every message where sender Id or receiver Id is mine and grab that user?

Comment: You don't have to 'check every message' you can query the conversation from a collection `where SenderId = [yourid] || ReceiverId = [yourid]`

Comment: That's what i'm telling about. Should i use group by user? @progrAmmar

Comment: That depends on your requirement. If you are only going to show received and sent for 1 user, you don't have to do a group by.

But if you are displaying a list of users (with a sublist of messages [something like a reddit thread]) then you may have to use group by